# Compress shapefiles into separate zip files reporting the filename prefix of the shapefiles

Tags: command-line, powershell, batch, zip

I have hundreds of shapefile structured files that I want to compress into separate zip files.
To be more precise, I have a folder with the following files (I list just some of them as an example):

- Grid_5_N0E0.dbf
- Grid_5_N0E0.prj
- Grid_5_N0E0.shp
- Grid_5_N0E0.shx
- Grid_5_N0E90.dbf
- Grid_5_N0E90.prj
- Grid_5_N0E90.shp
- Grid_5_N0E90.shx

My aim is to automatically generate zip files that contain the 4 files of each dataset and to have the zip file name that matches the dataset, as follows:

- Grid_5_N0E0.zip
- Grid_5_N0E90.zip

So far, I've found [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1022466/how-can-i-compress-every-10-files-in-a-folder-as-a-separate-zip-file?rq=1&newreg=bd2cdbbddb6648a0a66be000312ac2c6) that allows me to automatically create zip files each 'x' files by running this script in Windows PowerShell:

```
param
(
    # The input folder containing the files to zip
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $InputFolder,

    # The output folder that will contain the zip files
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $OutputFolder
)

Set-Variable SET_SIZE -option Constant -value 4
$i = 0
$zipSet = 0

Get-ChildItem $InputFolder | ForEach-Object {
    $zipSetName = "archive" + ($zipSet + 1) + ".zip"
    Compress-Archive -Path $_.FullName -Update -DestinationPath "$OutputFolder\$zipSetName"
    $i++;

    if ($i -eq $SET_SIZE) {
        $i = 0;
        $zipSet++;
    }
}
```

By setting the SET_SIZE value to 4 I'm able to automate this process, but as a result, I have

- archive1.zip
- archive2.zip
- etc.

Now I would find a way to tell the script to assign for each zip file the name of the files it contains (which is the same except for the extension), in order to have in return the zip files with these prefixes, as already explained:

- Grid_5_N0E0.zip
- Grid_5_N0E90.zip
- etc.

Is it possible to do so by implementing this script with the proper arguments?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Group-Object` to group the files on their BaseName. Use that same BaseName as the name for the zip file:

```
param (
    # The input folder containing the files to zip
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $InputFolder,

    # The output folder that will contain the zip files
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $OutputFolder
)

# make sure the destination folder for the zip files exists
$null = New-Item -Path $OutputFolder -ItemType Directory -Force

Get-ChildItem -Path $InputFolder -File | 
Where-Object { $_.Extension -match '\.(dbf|prj|shp|shx)' } |        # filter the files on allowed extensions
Group-Object BaseName | ForEach-Object {                            # group on the BaseName like 'Grid_5_N0E0'
    $zip = Join-Path -Path $OutputFolder -ChildPath $_.Name         # create the full path and filename for the zip file
    Compress-Archive -Path $_.Group.FullName -DestinationPath $zip  # compress the files in the group
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked smoothly